# Azure DevOps : permissions to add an existing user to an existing group

Tags: permissions, azure-devops

I have an user that has all the needed permissions to add users and groups, and edit collection and project level permissions for users and groups according this documentation: [Permissions and groups in Azure DevOps and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=vsts), but when he tries to add an existing user to an existing group in a project he receives "**You do not have the required permissions to perform this action**".

**User's collection level permissions:**

[image]

**User's project level permissions:**

[image]

**What I am missing? which permissions do I need to give him in order he is able to add existing users to existing groups?**

Comment: Your link appears to be broken. Is it supposed to go to the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=vsts

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Edit collection-level information" and "Edit project-level information" permissions are not enough. 
In order an user is able to add/remove users/groups to/from existing groups under an existing project, the user needs to be part of Project Administrator group at least.

Here you are the Azure DevOps developer community's answer:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/335367/cannot-give-right-permissions-for-adding-existing.html